# multiple js files per request vs 1 js file with multiple unused lines of code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, http

im building an application which by nature has a lot of flexibility and works on a component system which means any page could have 0-10's of components.

as the pages will be coming from a database my php code wont know which components are being used until after its been compiled.

each component could possibly have its own set of js functions (im using vue js but that isnt pertinent to the question).

now im stuck thinking whats going to be best from a http/load point of view.

the choices i have are:

1. create a js file for each component and selectively load each 1 when i detect its use (which also means a regex on the content via php before displaying).
2. have 1 big js file containing all components js and always load this 1 file.
3. have each component register its js as a string through php and have a dynamic url concatenate each used components js and send on page load

neither option is "easier" as 1 is easier on the js side but requires more php to detect and load the files. and 2 i can just use gulp to build a main concatentated file. 3 is probably the easiest but i know sending js via php is probably the least performant of the three.

option 1 would mean 10's of http request of small files

option 2 would be 1-2 http request but a larger file (in the order of 10's)

option 2 could also possibly mean only a small percentage of the js is used (or even none)

option 3 would mean different js urls for each page, more php compilation and less cacheability.

i can break down option 2 into 2 files (logged in js and logged out js) and always load the logged out and only load the logged in when a user is logged in which would help, and also set some serious caching on the file.

so anyone got any opinions on whats the route to go down?

im leaning towards option 2 considering the 1-2 requests and caching but dont want to get everything built and then rebuild it if i get big pushbacks because its the wrong way (this will be an open source project).

i know "test it and see" is a likley response but i must stress the project is in its early stages and will grow over time, so currently there are very few components, but there will be many in the future so need a route thats going to work based on 10's of components (i cant see it going into the 100's if that makes a difference).

i may have confused a few, basically the question is:

load x number of js files per page based on pages component usage (only js used is loaded)

or

load 1 file of js per page where js file contains all js even if not used on page (file likley to be 10x larger than individual file route)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to go is one/two files. don't sweat about the size, the browser will cache it on the first load  and it won't reload on each refresh. multiple files means multiple connections, and thats way slower

Answer (score 0):

There is no one way which is the best.

There are many things to take into consideration when thinking about this. Below are a few points that help you make a decision:

1- Generally, browsers can make 2-3 concurrent http request to a single URL from a single page. This means that if you load a lot of JS files separately, browser will only be downloading 2-3 resources at a time (js files, css files, images, media, etc...). This will of course slow down things. There are a couple of solutions for this problem, and they can be use together.

The **first** one would be to group all the js files into 1 cached js file. Yes, this would be a larger file, but with the proper cache headers along with heavy caching from ISPs and browsers for JS/CSS files, this would mean retrieving the file from the cache in the next visit. This would be a helpful option in case you have many returning visitors.

The **second** solution would be to load multiple resources from multiple subdomains/domains (ex: res.yourdomain.com, img.yourdomain.com, etc...). This would let the browser load your files simultaneously since they are from seperate "domains".

2- You have to balance the amount of processing used to select the proper js file using PHP regular expressions or other methods, versus loading the one big file.

The thing to consider here is if the js components are changing for the user per session. That means, if the user is able to navigate throughout your application and use these different components with one single click in one single session, I would rather have all the JS files loaded and cached so not to keep loading from copies that cannot be retrieved from the cache. Again, this would all be dependent on the total size of the JS files. But generally speaking, it would be better to load it once and then retrieve it from cache, of course if nothing is being written dynamically inside your JS file make it "un-cachable".

Bottom line, caching is an essential part in any big/high load application and you cannot go without it.

If you can provide more information about the specific architecture of the application and specific examples, i can edit the answer and provide more info.

Comment: thanks for your response, sounds a lot like option 2 which is what i figured would be the best approach.

Comment: for more info think of how wordpress has shortcodes, basically my components are a bit like shortcodes, so there could be none or lots of them on every different page of the site. the js for each could be anything from 30 lines (basic vuejs component) up to 100-200 lines.

Comment: when an admin creates a page they could add a "content" component, then below that they could add a "blog" component, and below that "share" component etc so its pretty flexible for the site owner.

Comment: 30 or 100/200 lines is nothing. You can even compress and minify. So, you should go with the one file thing to avoid a lot of http requests when calling the page. Make sure to have the proper cache headers in your htaccess to cache them heavily.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to have a few files for each part of my project:

- *core.min.js* - these are your core functions, or basically most often/quite frequently used modules.
- *default.min.js* - these are so-called "user" scripts and styles, for smaller projects where I can dump all non-core code in.
- *form.min.js*, *admin.min.js*, etc... - for specific portions of the site, or a single page (an additional HTTP request just for that page only wouldn't hurt, rather than downloading it from the home page.). Only if these specific scripts are **significant** in size.

I guess for your case, it would depend on how many pages there are that require numerous JS components, and the total number of JS component files you have. There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution and you would have to figure out which few files would be best to combine into one (as your **core** js) for your project.

It really depends on which is your limiting factor, do use a few tools like pingdom and Chrome's waterfall inspector to see bottlenecks, and experiment accordingly.

Honestly, if the filesize isn't huge, I would say just dump all core code into one, and scripts that you will modify over time in another (**two** JS files for entire site). However, if every page requires a different combination of JS files and they add up to a lot (in file size), split them up sparingly.